# Why am i losing the value of variable n2?

Tags: c, printf, double, scanf

I am doing school work and I came across a problem. Why do I loose the value of the variable `n2`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int opt;
double n1;
double n2;

int main()
{
    printf("Hello and welcome \n");
    printf("Lets do Some math! \n");
    printf("Menu!\n");
    printf("1- \t Areas \n");
    printf("2- \t Perimetros \n");
    scanf("%d",&opt);

    switch (opt){
        case 1:
            Areas();
            break;

        case 2:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Areas(){
    printf("Area de:\n");
    printf("1- \t Quadrado\n");
    printf("2- \t Retangulo\n");
    printf("3- \t Losangulo\n");
    printf("1- \t Circulo\n");
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    switch (opt){
        case 1:
            Medidas("dos lados.");
            printf("%d  %d\n", n1,n2 );
            break;

        case 2:
            break;
    }
}

void Medidas(char string[]){
    printf("Introduzir as Medidas %s \n", string);
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Next\n");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
}
```

I tried many things and nothing works. The

```
    printf("%d  %d\n", n1,n2 );
```

is just for debugging purposes.

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings.  That should have caught `double n1;
scanf("%d", &n1);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
 scanf("%d", &n1);
 scanf("%d", &n2);
```

`n1` and `n2` are of type `double`, so using `%d` format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2, for `fscanf()`, (*emphasis mine*)

> `d` 
>  Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as
>   expected for the subject sequence of the strtol function with the value 10
>   for the base argument. **The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to
>   signed integer.**

and

> [...] Unless assignment suppression was indicated by a *, the
>   result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following
>   the format argument that has not already received a conversion result. If this object
>   does not have an appropriate type, or if the result of the conversion cannot be represented
>   in the object, the behavior is undefined.

**solution:** For printing `double`s, you need to use `%f` and for scanning the values, you need to use `%lf`.

Answer (score 1):

The variables `n1` and `n2` are of type `double`.  However, you're using the `%d` format specifier in `printf` and `scanf`, which expect an `int` and a pointer to `int`.

For reading / writing a `double`, use the `%f` format specifier for `printf` and `%lf` for `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using double data type for `n1` and `n2`. 
The printing format specifier for double is `%f`; the scanning format is `%lf`. 
Instead of `%d`, use `%f` every time for `n1` and `n2`.

Comment: You should probably clarify your last sentence; using `%f` in a call to the `scanf()` family won't work with `n1` being a `double` — but it is fine for the `printf()` family.